# simple proxy server

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm trying to code a simple proxy server in C# using sockets (working on GET only atm), the code below "works", it does show the webpage via my proxy running but it's slow most of the time and always end up with socket exception which I have no idea how to deal with...[reference](http://royjin.wordpress.com/2010/08/13/c-basic-socket-programming-building-proxy-server/)

```
class ProxyServer {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        const int DEFAULT_PORT_NO = 27015;
        int port = -1;
        if(args.Length > 0 && args[0] != null) {
            port = Int32.Parse(args[0]); 
        } else if(port == -1) {
            port = DEFAULT_PORT_NO;
        }

        const int BACKLOG = 10;
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Loopback;
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(BACKLOG);
        Console.WriteLine(localEndPoint.ToString() + " Listening...\n");

        while(true) {
            Socket listenSocket = listener.Accept();
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler(listenSocket);
            Thread requestThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(requestHandler.handle));
            requestThread.Start();
        }
    }
}

class RequestHandler {
    private Socket serverSocket;

    public RequestHandler(Socket s) {
        serverSocket = s;
    }

    public void handle() {
        string header = getHeader(serverSocket);
        string host = getHost(header);
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(new Uri(host).Host);
        IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(addresslist[0], new Uri(host).Port);
        clientSocket.Connect(remoteEndPoint);
        sendRequest(clientSocket, header);

        header = getHeader(clientSocket);
        sendRequest(serverSocket, header);
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int receivedBytes = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);
        while(receivedBytes > 0) {
            serverSocket.Send(buffer, receivedBytes, SocketFlags.None);
            receivedBytes = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);
        }

        serverSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        serverSocket.Close();
    }

    string getHeader(Socket s) {
        string header = "";
        while(true){
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
            int bytesRec = s.Receive(bytes);
            header += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
            if (header.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n") > -1 || header.IndexOf("\n\n") > -1){
                break;
            }
        }
        return header;
    }

    string getHost(String h) {
        return h.Split(new char[] {'\n'})[0].Split(new char[] {' '})[1];
    }

    void sendRequest(Socket s, string h) {
        byte[] bytesSent = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(h);
        s.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    }

}
```

Pointers would be great...